# Is there a way to update Win10 OS build from 10586.318 to higher by update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to update Win10 **OS build** from 10586.318 to higher by update?

A few hours back I had automatic updates but the build is the same. Moreover, when I checked for updates manually there was nothing.

In this case, I have no idea how could I have higher builds (I need the build 14317.1000 or higher to install the new [Windows Subsystem for Linux - WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)).

By the way, here's a new [Facebook group for WSL support](https://www.facebook.com/groups/987976957946948/).

Comment: does it work? Do you also see Build 14342 in WU after updating to 14332?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There basically 2 options to do so:

### Option 1:

Join the insider Program with your Microsoft account and switch to Fast Ring

[image]

After 1 day you should get the option to update to Redstone 1 preview build.

### Option 2:

download the [ISO from Build 14332](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced), mount the ISO inside your current Windows 10, run `setup.exe` and select upgrade (keep all software/data or the option that you like).